# finding different value while doing regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, tolerance-interval

My question may sound unclear but I'm going to explain it in detail.

I have a data set includes two-column with 50 samples.

[image]

let's call the first column energy and the second column cracking.
Let's also give some background on what these numbers about.

The data is related to the materials on the road. The higher the energy the less cracking the road will be. However, having higher energy (while actually making those materials) is expensive.

And at the same time, not all the roads need those quality materials (high energy which leads to low cracking).

The goal is to come up with a threshold of energy (x-axis) which limits the cracking (y-axis). Alos, a reliability level would be needed for that threshold. Finally, we want to say, as an example, with a reliabilty of z%, an energy level of x, can limit the cracking to y.

I know that my explanations might still not be clear. please let me know which part needs more clarification.

My mind is blank which machine learning regression technique I can use for this problem.

**Update2**
y
This is the scatter plot and fitted line:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a scatterplot of cracking vs. energy? Also, is cracking related to traffic load (e.g. does higher traffic increase cracking)? If that's the case, it seems like you would need an additional column in your dataset measuring traffic load.

Comment: I have updated the question with scatter plot.

Comment: @user20160 after talking with my supervisor regarding your question, he said NO. the higher traffic will not increase the cracking. with this, do you think I can have an interval?

Comment: @user20160 I have updated my explanations. I think it should seem more understandable now.